Why do I get such poor performance in CUDA?
I have RTX 3050 under Linux, native NVidia driver. The same simple code performs on GPU 2.1GHz in 10 times slower than on CPU 2.4GHz. What may be wrong: driver, compiler flags, or this is normal performance?
The code is:
__global__ void testcuda() {
    uint counter = 0;
    do {
        if (++counter % 1000000000 == 0) printf("%u\n", counter);
    } while (counter != 0);
}

testcuda<<<1, 1>>>();

6 seconds on CPU and 47 seconds on GPU

Yes this is normal. GPU are really not designed for sequential scalar codes. GPU are designed for massively parallel SIMD codes. The large amount of parallelism is meant to make the code faster than on CPU which are good for sequential scalar code (benefiting from instruction-level parallelism) though modern CPUs have at least few cores and at least 4x32-bit SIMD units (often few of them).

Please review the CUDA programming guide and Best Practices Guide. Starting with the introduction of the programming guide: While the CPU is designed to excel at executing a sequence of operations, called a thread, as fast as possible and can execute a few tens of these threads in parallel, the GPU is designed to excel at executing thousands of them in parallel (amortizing the slower single-thread performance to achieve greater throughput).

By the way, your code does not have observable effect except the printf. A good CPU compiler can optimize out your loop and just write N times the printf value without incrementing the counter 1_000_000_000 times. They can get ride of the very slow modulus too. Oh and did you enabled optimizations for the CPU code? If yes, which flags?

OPTIMIZATION: yes, I do, but I'm novice in it. Please, tell me which flags may be significant. Currently they are: "--use_fast_math --default-stream=per-thread"

IDK which compiler you use, but for GCC/Clang, you should at least use -O2, or even -O3 (sometimes results in faster code at runtime but slower to build). On most mainstream x86-64 CPUs -mavx2 can also help but probably not here. --use_fast_math is useless here because it only applies on floating-point numbers and there are none here (not to mention it can be dangerous btw).

From NVidia forum: Hm… I have only 2304 cores, but this test is not in twice long…
testcuda<<<18, 256>>>();
52 seconds (instead of 47+47)
testcuda<<<18, 1024>>>();
98 seconds – it is more 18000 iterations. So, use more threads than in HW spec.

With testcuda<<<18, 256>>>();, you run 4608 times the same computation (so 4608 times more work) which is insane! CUDA does not automatically parallelize the code for you. This is your job by manually splitting the work so each threads compute an independent part. Please read the CUDA developer manual, tutorials and examples. All of this is already explained in them.

Guys, it is only in CUDA I'm a novice, but about a professor in parallel computing in general :) So, do not criticize my nice powerful TEST -- it is very helpful

The test is fine. It's the assumption that a single GPU thread could hold a candle to a CPU thread which betrays an utter lack of research before asking this question. There are no dumb questions but on SO you are expected to make a minimal effort to answer them yourself before posting

But it is finally TRUE, 6 seconds on CPU and 5 seconds on GPU -- the result of my todays' work is a speedup in 10 times!

The GPU is a parallel machine, a massively parallel machine.
If you look at the GPU chip, you'll notice that it has 2560 execution cores, whereas your CPU has only (say) 8.
The two chip occupy more or less the same surface area though, meaning that the CPU cores are about 2560/8 = 320 times bigger.
All that extra area is used to decrease the latency of the CPU, by using pipelining, branch prediction, stack engine, out-of-order execution, superscalar execution, speculative cache prefetching, and more besides.
The GPU cores with their tiny allotment of transistors have none of these features. Instead the GPU focuses on executing lots of statements in parallel using a scheme similar to SIMD, which NVidia calls: SIMT.
This means that the GPU works fastest when all threads are executing the same instructions on different data.
In your example, you run only a single thread, meaning that 2559 threads are idling and you thus run more than 2000x slower than you could have done, if you had been able to fully parallelize your code.
Parallelizing code is non-trivial for sure, but if you are able you'll see the benefit of the GPU.
How big a speedup you can achieve depends on the amount of parallel work you can extract from your code, which is governed by Amdahl's law.
A normal latency for a GPU thread is 7 or 8 GPU cycles, the CPU typically has a latency of 1/2 a cycle (less than one due to pipelining, instruction re-ordering, and superscalar execution).
Considering that the CPU has 8 cores, you'll have to extract at least 8 x 8 = 64x *) parallelism before you can expect the GPU to outperform the CPU.
*) this is just an indication and can vary widely depending on the application, data access patterns, etc.

You are using only 1 cuda thread which uses only 1 warp which belongs only 1 SM unit in GPU. You gpu has 64 active warps and even more active threads in-flight capability.
When you do this on CPU, it is missing only 8x - 16x performance of single core. But on GPU, it is missing 2048x performance. Since GPU pipelines have worse branch-prediction, worse stack management, worse frequencies and many other specs, it is not useful to compare single CUDA thread performance to single CPU thread performance. Single GPU thread represents 0.1% of GPU compute power. But on CPU it can get close to 10% with some compiler optimizations such as vectorization. But CUDA compiler does not auto-vectorize these loops to map them to multiple pipelines. CUDA compiler only lets you write single-thread code and expect you to be responsible for synchronizations, reductions and other parallel primitives using thousands of threads. So you have to use enough number of threads to keep GPU pipelines busy.
Even if you have launched 1000 threads using 1000 pipelines, it would take no less time than that as all threads run the same kernel. You need to explicitly distribute the work to the threads. Something like 1000 iterations per thread, on 1000000 threads. Maybe 1000000 threads is too much. But a GPU should have threads about 16-24x the number of pipelines to be kept fully occupied.
If CUDA had some kind of auto-vectorization for simple loops just like GCC does, it could work. But even then, you are not giving it a proper loop. There is a dependency chain in that loop because of printf. Even GCC can not auto-vectorize that printf function.
Think about RTX3050 as a cluster of Pentium-2000s(without even SSE) stacked together or a super-computer from 20 years ago. Without proper code, only single processor of super computer is used.

When I run my test as  testcuda<<<18, 1024>>>() -- it is pure PARALLEL code. It does not matter there are no vectors, no matrices. And about pipelines: in SIMD architecture, theoretically, there are single flow of instructions, why must it be worst than on CPU?

@AlexDem "why must it be worst than a CPU?" CPUs support maybe 100 threads. GPGPUs start at a few thousand and can go up to more than 100,000. If we knew how to make threads that are individually as fast as a CPU thread and as numerous as a GPGPU thread, we wouldn't need to make GPGPUs. We'd just build our CPUs that way. But we can't. Instead, GPGPUs have in-order execution with no branch prediction, long instruction and memory latency, limitations to their independent thread scheduling, memory access patterns, etc.

SIMD is something different... It looks like single thread, applied many times to various data
